# How to handle layout containers which do not match component hierarchy?

Tags: reactjs, layout, dom-manipulation

As far as I've understood, in React, components should communicate in an hierarchical order through the nested hierarchy. Given this, how should it be handled when an application's layout container structure don't match the natural/expected/logical component hierarchy.

As an example of my question, I've come up with a scenario based on my app, that I'm not sure how to implement properly:

> The screen is split vertically in two halves. This is done having two
>   div containers side by side. To each halve there's a corresponding
>   component: **ItemsList** and **ItemDetails**.
>
> Nested inside **ItemsList**, there are several **Item** components we can
>   click on.
>
> Each time there is click on an **Item**, the corresponding defined *_itemID* prop value needs to be sent to **ItemDetails** so it can load and display **Item** details in there.

The problem is, given the component structure, how can **ItemDetails** be a child of **Item** and still be on the right section of the screen where it's intended to be. (At least without some weird CSS which I want to avoid).

Here's the layout:

```
<div className="wrapper">
    <div className="itemList" style="width:50%; display:inline-block;">
        <div className="item">item1</div>
        <div className="item">item1</div>
        <div className="item">item1</div>
    </div>

    <div className="itemDetails" style="width:50%; display:inline-block;">
        The details of the selected item.
    </div>

</div>
```

I believe I could send information from a child to parent following up the hierarchy, but this don't seem practical. Considering this scenario is just a simplification of my actual problem (I have a lot more nested components), I believe this would make the code messy and confuse.

Is there a clean, simple way to achieve this in React? Am I missing some concept?

Answer (score 2):

If it were me I would have a container component based off your wrapper. It would handle all state changes and be the source of truth for what the currently selected item is. Then you'd just need to pass a callback from the wrapper component through props down to your ItemsList that would handle setting the state of the active item.

Then you can just pass activeItem as a prop to the itemDetails component. It is a fairly common pattern to have a container component that manages state and passes callback functions down to child components that would allow them to create an action that changes the state of the container

The heirarchy would look like:

```
<Wrapper> // holds the state of active item and provides functions to change the active item
 <ItemList /> // provides a list of items that when clicked sets active
 <ItemDetail /> // shows the detail of the currently select item
</Wrapper>
```

Here is a pen of what i'm trying to explain

http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/KgEzgE

Answer (score 1):

This always depends on many things. **If you intend for a small project you are fine working with setState and refer to finalfreq's great answer.** If you intend to scale well (aka grow without pain) then I would opt for a state management library.

I hate to be the guy who answers a simple question with "Use ... library! It's awesome!", and like I said, it really does not get much better than finalFreq's answer if you don't have the need to grow your app. A redux author even mentions that you should learn react without redux first, and you should not reach for it until you have a real need.

If you use redux then you should never have to worry about component structure for the sake of passing scope. Component structure if I am not mistaken(which I often am XD) should be based on what is easiest to understand and maintain, also performance comes to mind.

Your question is in the context of react, but I think this is really a state management and data communication question. I opt for redux.js lately(a pub/sub like library), but there are many alternatives. Redux requires a bit more typing, but offers extreme explicitness that you may appreciate as the project grows.

[But the main reason I would reach for this is that it focuses on functional programming principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733712/is-applying-functional-programming-principles-to-javascript-a-seriously-viable-o), and pushes your state mutations to the outer fringes of your app. This simplifies your code. If there is a bug it's easy to find(All mutations should be in the reducer files. You would also move your calculations to a util file which simplifies your code even more)

http://redux.js.org/